# My code never reaches the protocol stub of my delegate class

Tags: swift, swiftui, appdelegate, tuya

I'm new on iOS development, I'm making an IoT app using the TuyaSDK (I've already done the Android version of the App), the problem comes when I pair the device, it uses a delegate to listen wether the device is or isn't successfully paired. I can pair the device but it seems that my code never reaches the protocol of my delegate.
This is my code:

```
    import SwiftUI
    import TuyaSmartHomeKit
    import TuyaSmartDeviceKit
    import Toast
    import TuyaSmartActivatorKit

    struct HomeDevices: View{
    
        @State var homeId: Int64 = 0
        @State var token: String = ""
        @State var devId: String = ""
        @State var device: TuyaSmartDevice?
     
  
        let homeManager: TuyaSmartHomeManager = TuyaSmartHomeManager()
        
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Button("Crear casa"){
                    addHome()
                }.font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(width:150, height:20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color("colorbotones"))
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                    .offset(y:-100)
                Button("Encender"){
                    
                    publishDps(estado : true)
                }.font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(width:150, height:20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color("colorbotones"))
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                    .offset(y:30)
                
                Button("Apagar"){
                    
                    publishDps(estado : false)
                }.font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .frame(width:150, height:20)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color("colorbotones"))
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                    .offset(y:90)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        func addHome() {
            homeManager.addHome(withName: "Home",
                                geoName: "Bolivia",
                                rooms: ["Quantum"],
                                latitude: 0,
                                longitude: 0,
                                success: { (homeId) in
                // The value of `homeId` for the home.
                print("add home success")
                print(homeId)
                getToken(homeId: homeId)
            }) { (error) in
                if let e = error {
                    print("add home failure: \(e)")
                }
            }
        }
        
        func getToken(homeId : Int64){
            TuyaSmartActivator.sharedInstance()?.getTokenWithHomeId(homeId, success: { (token)      in
                print("getToken success: \(String(describing: token))")
                startConfigWiFi(token: token!)
                // TODO: startConfigWiFi
            }, failure: { (error) in
                if let e = error {
                    print(homeId)
                    print("getToken failure: \(e)")
                }
            })
        }
    func startConfigWiFi(token: String) {
        let delegate = tuyaSmartActivatorDelegate.init()
        delegate.StartSync(token: token)
    }

        func publishDps(estado : Bool) {
            device = TuyaSmartDevice(deviceId: "eb153db66617bd33e5dvi1") //I'm manually passing the deviceID
    
            let dps = ["1" : estado]
            device?.publishDps(dps, success: {
                 print("publishDps success")

                // The DP is sent and the callback of status reporting is implemented with the    `deviceDpsUpdate` method.
            }, failure: { (error) in
                if let e = error {
                    print("publishDps failure: \(e)")
                }
            })
        }
        
    }

    
    struct HomeDevices_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            HomeDevices()
        }
    }
class tuyaSmartActivatorDelegate: NSObject, TuyaSmartActivatorDelegate {
    override init() {
   super.init()
        TuyaSmartActivator.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        
     }
    func StartSync(token:String){
        TuyaSmartActivator.sharedInstance()?.startConfigWiFi(TYActivatorModeEZ, ssid: "QUANTUM", password: "almacenqnt22*", token: token, timeout: 1000)
        }
        
    //MARK: - TuyaSmartActivatorDelegate
//My code never reaches this protocol stub//
    func activator(_ activator: TuyaSmartActivator!, didReceiveDevice deviceModel: TuyaSmartDeviceModel!, error: Swift.Error!) {
        print("Anything")
    }
    
    }
```

I've tried calling the protocol manually like this:
[example on how I tried to force the code to enter the protocol of the delegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2tMs.png)
what I'm expecting is to get a response from the "func activator()" in order to know if the device was paired or not.
Something like this:

```
func activator(_ activator: TuyaSmartActivator!, didReceiveDevice deviceModel: TuyaSmartDeviceModel!, error: Error!) {
    if deviceModel != nil && error == nil {
        // The device is paired.
        //Do something
    }

    if let e = error {
        // Failed to pair the device.
        print("\(e)")
    }
}
```

accordind to the samples provided by Tuya IoT platform, it should work without manually calling the "fun activator()"

Comment: The delegate is a local variable. Meaning that it should be released/dealloc at the end of the scope (ie ~ at the next closing `}`). So when the `TuyaSmartActivator.sharedInstance` want to reach its delegate to cal `activator(_: didReceiveDevice:error:)`, it's nil. Make it a property of your object, to keep the delegate "alive" as long as its parent/owner (your `HomeDevices: View`).

Comment: @Larme could you please provide me an example on how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where you wrote `let homeManager: TuyaSmartHomeManager = TuyaSmartHomeManager()`, add under it `let delegate = tuyaSmartActivatorDelegate.init()`.

Comment: @Larme OMG IT WORKED!!!  Thank you so much, I'm in debt to you.